# AJAX contact form in CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, contact-form

Few questions:

I'm using CI and JQuery AJAX.

In my code below, I assemble `dataString`, which by default, is appended to the URL as a query string.

I've changed the AJAX "type" to POST, so my question is - how do I access `dataString` in my CI app?

It would seem I still have to use

`$name=$this->input->post('name')`

Which to me, makes setting `dataString` redundant?

--

I've tried searching but can't really find anything concrete.

Would it be possible to still make use of CIs validation library and AJAX?

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    // what can i return so that my CI app shows errors?
}
```

Normally you would reload the contact form or redirect the user. In an ideal world I would like the error messages to be shown to the user.

**Jquery:**

```
    $(document).ready(function($){
        $("#submit_btn").click(function(){
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var company = $("input#company").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var dataString = 'name=' +  name + '&message=' + message + '&return_email=' + email + '&return_phone=' +
            phone + '&company=' + company;
            var response = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "newsite/contact_ajax/",
                data: dataString
            }).responseText;

            //$('#contact').hide();
            //$('#contact').html('<h5>Form submitted!  Thank you!</h5><h4>We will be in touch with you soon.</h4>');
            //$('#contact').fadeIn('slow');
            return false;
        });  
    });
```

hope i've been clear enough - if anyone has a decent example of a CI contact form that would be great. there's mixed stuff on the internet but nothing that hits all the boxes.

thanks

Comment: `data: $(your_form_id).serialize(),` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, you don't need to set a `dataString` since jQuery can do it for you:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $("#submit_btn").click(function(){
        var response = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "newsite/contact_ajax/",
            data: $(your_form_id).serialize()
        }).responseText;

        //$('#contact').hide();
        //$('#contact').html('<h5>Form submitted!  Thank you!</h5><h4>We will be in touch with you soon.</h4>');
        //$('#contact').fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    });  
});
```

Comment: so `dataString` is strictly for GET right? makes sense i suppose. So I'd just access data from form variables in the standard CI way? `data:` becomes a makeshift POST array? thanks ~

Comment: No, please read [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), don't get confused when using $.ajax you are no longer using the classic form submission (the form is more like data holder now and a fallback if JS is disabled)...the browser is submitting to the `url` whatever you provide it, so the `data` is used for both `POST` and `GET` requests, what the serialize() is doing just saving your time and preparing the `dataString` for you!

Answer (score 3):

If you use the jQuery [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) function, you can explicitly name the post variables, then access them in your controller the way you suggested in your question.

```
 $.post("<?php echo site_url("newsite/contact_ajax/";?>",
        {my_name:name,my_company:company,my_email:email,my_phone:phone,my_message:message},
        function(){
              //callback function
         },    
         html
      );
```

In Your controller:

```
$this->input->post('my_name');
$this->input->post('my_company');
//etc
```